# Is $f(x)=|x\sin x|$ positive and not bounded function

Tags: calculus

Can I say that the function $f(x)=|x\sin x|$ is positive not bounded and doesn't have a point that converges to infinity?

Thank you!

Comment: It is 1. positive 2. unbounded. I don't understand what about the point that converges to infinite. $f(x)$ does not converge as $x\to\infty$ and the set partial limits of $f(x_n)$ is all non-negative reals.

Comment: @Ilya, with a light explanation more your comment is actually an answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio: thanks for suggestion, done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can't say the $f$ is positive, as it frequently take value $0 $(when $x_k = k\cdot\pi$ for $k\in \Bbb Z$) so you can only say that $f$ is non-negative.
2. $f$ is unbounded since for $y_k = \frac\pi2+k\cdot\pi$ you have $f(y_k) = y_k$ as $\sin y_k =1$.
3. I am not sure, what did you mean by saying

   > and doesn't have a point that converges to infinity

   but what can be said is that the limit $\lim _{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist. Just consider values of $f$ over sequences $x_k$ and $y_k$. Even worse (better?): for any $a\in [0,\infty)$ there exists a sequence $a_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = a.$